# Consistency for MRTK2's IMixedRealityPointerHandler

Tags: hololens, mrtk

The raw position and rotation data of the `IMixedRealityPointerHandler` output isn't consistent across all users with the same hand gesture-- what strategies can we use to make this more consistent over various users? Does the device train to a specific eye calibration more accurately over time i.e. does more time in the device = better eye/hand tracking for that user?

Comment: Hi, can you provide some examples? I think you mean something like "when a user performs a select gesture sometimes their hand moves by 1 cm amount and sometimes it moves by 2 cm", but I'm not sure. Some specific data would be helpful. As a suggestion, you could try smoothing the data  by using a simple EWMA filter. Here is a great book on the topic: https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The raw position and rotation data of the IMixedRealityPointerHandler output isn't consistent across all users with the same hand gesture

I’m not sure my understanding is correct, it looks like what you are talking about is, HoloLens lacks data consistency in the recognition of the same gesture by different users.

Actually, when users making any gestures on HoloLens, they need to keep his hands within the "Gesture Frame", in a range that the gesture-sensing cameras can see appropriately.
For this reason, the user needs to be trained in this area of recognition both for the success of the action and for their comfort.

For best results, three things mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/gestures#gesture-frame)  are essential to improve the consistency of gesture recognition:

1. Users need to be aware of Gesture Frame's existence.
2. Notifying users when their gestures are nearing/breaking the gesture frame boundaries within an application.
3. Consequences of breaking the gesture frame boundaries should be minimized.

Besides, we highly recommend that running **Calibration** each time a different person uses the device(please navigate to Setting->Utilities->Calibration).